# Locking cells in Google Sheets at a specific time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to code my Google Sheets cells in a way that certain cells automatically lock at a specific time every day. I should be able to edit it, but not my collaborators.

How do I pull this off?

In the sample sheet (<strike>[link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Az51IGA-OOt6ML6KMOzlVT8QwoFe5nhzH7yK26sQFG8/edit?usp=sharing)</strike>), you will see certain dates (15/7/2015-17/7/2015). I want to code it so that each date (eg `A1:B6`) is locked daily, 10 pm.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()) + a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), probably

Comment: Should it be locked for everyone? And shall it unlock at anytime?

Comment: Yeah, locked for everyone (myself as editor not included) and it would be nice to manually unlock it later

Comment: So basically...I work with some collaborators and they can edit the doc. Right now when I lock some cells via protected ranges, I tick off some collaborators.

What I'm planning now is to also tick off some collaborators when the cells automatically lock based on time driven trigger or so

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [@NightShadeQueen suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625064/locking-cells-in-google-sheets-at-a-specific-time#comment51204712_31625064) a combination of [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and the [protect()-method of the Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()) can be used.

1. Open the script editor in the sheet (*Tools > Script editor...*)
2. Create code that locks the ranges, might look something like this:

---

*You'll have to modify the code if your sheet doesn't look like the Sample sheet. Especially the `lockRanges()`-function, which defines which ranges should be protected. Currently, it starts with cell `A1`, and steps down 7 rows at a time until the end of the sheet is reached.*

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //INSERT SHEET NAME HERE

function lockRanges() {
  //First cell to lock
  var row = 1;
  var col = 1;

  // Get last row with data in sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Loop until last row in sheet is passed
  while(row <= lastRow){
    //Lock current cell
    lockRange(row, col);

    // Go to row 7 steps down from current (the next date)
    row = row + 7;
  }
}



function lockRange(row, col){
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);

  // Create protection object. Set description, anything you like.
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected, row ' + row);

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

3. Add the Time-driven trigger

   1. Still in the Script editor; go to *Resources > Current project's triggers*.
   2. Create a new trigger
   3. Choose `Run` = `lockRanges`
   4. Choose `Events` = `Time-driven`, `Day timer`, `10pm to 11pm` (or whenever you want)

> NOTE: The time may be slightly randomized [(read more)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect())

---

That's it, now the ranges will be protected at the time you chose. As with ranges you protect manually, they show up in *Data > Protected sheets and ranges*.

Something unclear? Ask away!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Just one update in the above
**Current project's triggers** moved to **Edit** menu