# Lock Google Sheet tab based on date+time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google worksheet with a specific sheet I'd like to protect from editing based on date and time. I saw code for doing this for specific cell(s), but I want to do it for the entire sheet and to keep the list of editors (just protect from public editing).

I've tried to use some code I found here: [Locking cells in Google Sheets at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625064/locking-cells-in-google-sheets-at-a-specific-time/31631220) but not sure how to modify this code for my use case.

EDIT:

Looking closer at this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection it appears the following code would help:

```
// Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected  range');

// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
```

However, how do I declare the specific sheet name? I have multiple tabs in my spreadsheet. What is getActive going to pull?

Comment: Welcome. If you didn't this yet, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. Then comeback and edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: I added more context, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, how do I declare the specific sheet name? I have multiple tabs in my spreadsheet. What is getActive going to pull?

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` returns a Spreadsheet object representing the spreadsheet that holds the code it the script is a bounded script or the spreadsheet that called a function the add-on that holds the script.

Use [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to get a Sheet object by it's name.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to modify the code and get a working result for the specific sheet.